# Is it possible to create your own animoji within iOS 11

Tags: ios11, arkit

I've seen ARkit and I've seen the demo for animoji on the keynote, but I'm wondering if there is a way to create your own animoji (that will work within messages) within Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ARKit` to provide facial movement data to animate your own 3D models. In conjunction with an iMessage app, you should be able to export videos of animated characters similar to animojis.

Take a look at `ARBlendShapeLocation` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arblendshapelocation)) which provides high-level facial feature detection. You could track these features and use them to animate your models.

I'd also recommend watching the recent Apple developer video called "Face Tracking with ARKit" ([link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/601/)) which gives a good overview of the API's available.

When you're ready to jump right in, start with this face-tracking sample code ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences)) from Apple. (thanks @rickster)

Note that these features are only available on the new iPhone X.

Comment: Adding to that set of links: Apple has a [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences) project that shows how to use the various face tracking AR features. Looks like one of the things in there uses blend shapes to animate a character, like Animoji.

Comment: To underscore @nathan's other point: from the [announcement video](https://www.apple.com/apple-events/september-2017/) it seems Animoji are just looping video when sent as iMessages, so to replicate what Apple does you'd be recording video of whatever you create with ARKit, and then using the [Messages API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation) to send it.